# stability of fixed/equilibrium points in system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

Given is the following system $(a>0)$: 
$$\dot{x}=x(1-x)-xy$$
$$\dot{y}=y(ax-1)$$
In order to find the fixed points I have set $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ equal to zero and found $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $(\frac{1}{a},1-\frac{1}{a})$. To inspect the stability of these I have set up the Jacobian matrix as follows:
\begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{\partial \dot{x}}{\partial x} & 
    \frac{\partial \dot{x}}{\partial y} \\[1ex] % <-- 1ex more space between rows of matrix
  \frac{\partial \dot{y}}{\partial x} & 
    \frac{\partial \dot{y}}{\partial y} \\
\end{bmatrix} 
Which is 
\begin{bmatrix}
  1-2x-y & 
    -x \\[1ex] % <-- 1ex more space between rows of matrix
  ay & 
    ax-1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
For the point $(1,0)$ this would yield: 
\begin{bmatrix}
  -1 & 
    -1 \\[1ex] % <-- 1ex more space between rows of matrix
  0 & 
    a-1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
Which has the eigenvalues $\lambda_1=-1$ and $\lambda_2=a-1$.

Going through the same process for the point $(\frac{1}{a},1-\frac{1}{a})$ gives the eigenvalues: 
[image] Which is massive and I have no idea what to do with this.

For the point $(0,0)$ I get the eigenvalues $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=-1$ which at least is clear to me that is a unstable saddle point.

> - Sketch the linearised system for each fixed point where $a<1$ and make
>     clear what kind of fixed point it is (saddle, centre, focus).

As far as I know I have linearised the system already to find the stability of the found fixed points so this question confuses me. For $(0,0)$ I believe it's a saddle and for $(1,0)$ where $a<1$ we end up with two negative eigenvalues causing a stable node. But $(\frac{1}{a},1-\frac{1}{a})$ is still a puzzle to me.

> - Take $a<1$. Sketch the nullclines. Find the signs of $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$.

For the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ this is clear for me but the other one not so much.

> - Look at the solutions with initial values $(x_0,y_0)$ for $0 < a \leq 1$ and where $x_0>0$ and $y_0\geq 0$. Find the limit for all these solutions for when $t$ goes to infinity.

Any explanation or hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you have miscalculated the points of equilibrium, since I get these:
$$P_1\left(0,0\right)\qquad P_2\left(1,0\right)\qquad P_3\left(\frac{1}{a},1-\frac{1}{a}\right)$$

Comment: yup you're right. I've edited the question with the right points now.

Comment: Sorry but... I think something is wrong with your eigenvalues for $P_3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\,P_3\left(\frac{1}{a},1-\frac{1}{a}\right)\,$ your Jacobian matrix is
$$\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{a}&-\frac{1}{a}\\\;\,a-1&\;\;0\;\end{pmatrix}$$

so, when you look for the eigenvalues you should get
$$\lambda=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-4a\left(a-1\right)}}{2a}$$
which is a real solution only if $\;0<a<\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

You solved for the fixed points wrong. They should be (0,0), (1,0), and (1/a, 1-1/a). Using those will fix your problem.

Comment: putting $\dot{y}=0$ gives $y(ax-1)=0$ leading to $y=0$ and $x=\frac{1}{a}$. I can't see how you have found the last point unless you use a different method to find the fixed points? In that case could you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: You get y(ax-1)=0 like you said, but that means either y=0 OR x=1/a. If y=0 then to satisfy the first equation you need x=0 or 1. If x=1/a you need y=1-1/a in order to satisfy the first equation. Does that make sense? Also, sorry about the bad formatting I’m typing this on my phone.

Comment: No problem. I understand what you mean now. I'll edit my question with this new information and will move forward. Thanks for the help.